# How to visualize the result to show only 3 rows

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I`m trying to show in my table only 3 rows and they need to contain from Calendar_month_number numbers 4,5,6
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzYgY.png

any suggestions

```
    select s.PROD_ID,t.DAY_NUMBER_IN_MONTH,t.CALENDAR_MONTH_NUMBER,sum(s.AMOUNT_SOLD)
from CUSTOMERS c join SALES s
on c.CUST_ID=s.CUST_ID
join TIMES t
on s.TIME_ID=t.TIME_ID
where s.PROD_ID = 5
and t.TIME_ID BETWEEN '01-APR-00'and '01-JUL-00'
group by s.PROD_ID,t.DAY_NUMBER_IN_MONTH,t.CALENDAR_MONTH_NUMBER
having sum(s.AMOUNT_SOLD) > 0;
```

Comment: there are number in the column 4-5-6, i need to show one row from each number

Comment: aggregate the result so that it contains only 3 rows, and need to show one row for each number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, apparently this would be

```
select t.CALENDAR_MONTH_NUMBER,sum(s.AMOUNT_SOLD)
  from CUSTOMERS c
  INNER JOIN SALES s
    on c.CUST_ID=s.CUST_ID
  INNER JOIN TIMES t
    on s.TIME_ID=t.TIME_ID
  where s.PROD_ID = 5 and
        t.TIME_ID BETWEEN '01-APR-00'and '01-JUL-00'
  group by t.CALENDAR_MONTH_NUMBER
  having sum(s.AMOUNT_SOLD) > 0;
```